# How to get the branch that the PR is heading to in CircleCI

Tags: circleci, circleci-2.0, circleci-workflows

CircleCI have a `CIRCLE_BRANCH` env variable that tells you the name of the branch of the PR itself.

But I want the other way around, I need the branch name of the PR is trying to merge against.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply set that by using github api and set the parameters tag for it to reuse same value under step runs.

```
parameters:
  target-branch:
    type: string
    default: '$(curl -s -H "Authorization: token ${GITHUB_TOKEN}" $(echo https://api.github.com/repos/${CIRCLE_PULL_REQUEST:19} | sed "s/\/pull\//\/pulls\//") | jq ".base.ref" | tr -d "\042" )'
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no built-in environment variable (see full list [here](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/env-vars/#built-in-environment-variables)) to get the name of the base branch of a pull request. You could however get the pull request number using the `CIRCLE_PR_NUMBER` environment variable and use the GitHub REST API to retrieve the base branch name.

You're going to need to:

1. [Create a GitHub personal access token](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line) using the `repo` scope
2. [Set a project environment variable](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/env-vars/#setting-an-environment-variable-in-a-project) called `GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN`
3. [Retrieve the pull request data in JSON format](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#get-a-single-pull-request)
4. Parse the JSON to get the base branch ref - [there's a few ways to achieve that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1955555/579717)

Here's a sample bash script that retrieves a given pull request's data in JSON format and parses it using Python 2:

```
#!/bin/bash

REPO_OWNER="replace_me"
GITHUB_API_URL="https://api.github.com/repos/$REPO_OWNER/$CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME/pulls/$CIRCLE_PR_NUMBER?access_token=$GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN"
export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8
export PULL_REQUEST_BASE_REF=$(curl -s "$GITHUB_API_URL" | python -c "import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)['base']['ref']")
```